# Is there a way to have parallel for loops in HTML?

Tags: python, html, list, for-loop

I am using Python FLask to build a webapp and I am trying to push a nested list to a table in HTML.

**Python**

```
item = [[22-03-20, $1409.50, 22-03-20], [22-03-20, $60.00, 22-03-20]]
```

**current HTML**

```
{% for rows in item %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">•</th>
      {% for cell in rows %}
        <td>{{cell}}</td>
      {% endfor %}
     <td><a href="{{cell}}">edit</a></td>
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

The reason for a duplicate of dates in the nested list is because I need to create a special route page to the date itself.

Output I want to achieve
[image: Output]

Basically, the edit will redirect to the page to the respective date. As I have multiple expenses of the same date, I can't just use the unique id within the table.

**PROBLEM**

The current HTML I have is able to output the 3 items I need, date, expense, date but I can't put a URL redirect to the 3rd variable, date. Is there a way to have 2 for loops running parallel to each other, so I could go through 2 lists at the same time? or is there a better way to do what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Found a way looking through the documentation again, don't need a parallel for loop actually. I changed the nested list to a tuple in a list. Not sure if this is the best way to do it though.

**Python**

```
item = [(22-03-20, $1409.50, 22-03-20), (22-03-20, $60.00, 22-03-20)]
```

**HTML**

```
{% for x,y,z in item %}
<tr>
<th scope="row">•</th>
<td>{{x}}</td>
<td>{{y}}</td>
<td><a href="{{z}}">edit</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use a list of maps.

```
item = [
    {
        'date':'22-03-20',
        'price':'$1409.50',
        'href':'URI'
    },
    {
        'date':'22-03-20',
        'price':'$60.00',
        'href':'URI'
    },
]
```

so,

```
{% for row in item %}
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">•</th>
        <td>{{row.date}}</td>
        <td>{{row.price}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="{{row.href}}">edit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```